# How to save remote IP address in Postgres with Go?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-chi

I am trying to save incoming request's remote IP address into Postgres. I am using `chi` and `sqlc`.

Here's the migration:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ips (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    ip INET
);
```

And this is the insert query:

```sql
-- name: CreateIp :one
INSERT INTO ips (
    ip
) VALUES (
    $1
) RETURNING *;
```

This is the struct for params:

```golang
type CreateIpParams struct {
    Ip        net.IP         `json:"ip"`
}
```

Get the IP and parse it:

```golang
...

    // Get IP from RemoteAddr
    ip, _, _ := net.SplitHostPort(r.RemoteAddr)
    log.Println(" >> ip:", reflect.ValueOf(ip)) // ::1
    log.Println(" >> ip.TypeOf:", reflect.TypeOf(ip)) // string

    if netIp := net.ParseIP(ip); netIp != nil {
        params.Ip = netIp
        log.Println(" >> netIp:", reflect.ValueOf(netIp)) // ::1
        log.Println(" >> netIp.TypeOf:", reflect.TypeOf(netIp)) // net.IP
    }

...
```

When I made a `POST` request, it returns:

```
    "error": "pq: invalid byte sequence for encoding \"UTF8\": 0x00"
```

If I removed the that code block without saving ip at all:

```
    "error": "pq: invalid input syntax for type inet: \"\""
```

I tried trimming the `ip` with `strings.TrimSpace(ip)` but doesn't help.

Code with `sqlc` save.

```golang
...
    params := &db.CreateIpParams{}

    // Get IP from RemoteAddr
    ip, _, _ := net.SplitHostPort(r.RemoteAddr)
    if netIp := net.ParseIP(ip); netIp != nil {
        params.Ip = netIp
    }

    if _, err := db.NewPg(pg).CreateIp(context.Background(), *params); err != nil {
        render.Render(w, r, ErrRender(err))
        return
    }
```

`CreateIp` code and `Ip` struct:

```golang
// db/user.sql.go

func (q *Queries) CreateIp(ctx context.Context, arg CreateIpParams) (Ip, error) {
    row := q.queryRow(ctx, q.createIpStmt, createIp,
        arg.Ip,
    )
    var i Ip
    err := row.Scan(
        &i.Ip,
    )
    return i, err
}

// db/models.go

type Ip struct {
    ID         int64          `json:"id"`
    Ip         net.IP         `json:"ip"`
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated with the code that save with `sqlc`.

Comment: Can you show how `CreateIp` looks like, regardless of whether it's generated or handwritten?

Comment: Sure thing, I've added.

Comment: Looks ok, one more thing: Is the parameter parsing and saving happening in one and the same function? or is it done by separate functions? If it's done by separate function are you certain you're passing a pointer to that function? Try adding a log/print statement to the generated `CreateIp` to see if the `arg` has the `Ip` field set or not, if not then that would mean that you're passing around copies of params somewhere where you should be passing pointers instead.

Comment: You need to focus your question a bit more. You are asking how to save the IP, but in code, you are giving QueryRow() which is not for saving but retrieving data from QW.

Comment: @MayankPatel that's generated code, and it's correct for INSERTs that have the RETURNING clause.

Comment: @MayankPatel I added "generated" to explain it, but Flimzy edited that out for some reason.

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, parameters parsing and saving are in one and the same function in one file under one package `auth`.

Comment: @Rario and have you tried adding the print statement to the generated `CreateIp` method?

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, I just did. I added `log.Println(" >> IP here:", arg.Ip)` right above `query.Row()`, it prints `2020/10/06 20:39:42  >> IP here: ::1`

Comment: @Rario then this is gonna be an issue with how the driver handles `net.IP`, or maybe `sqlc` should not use `net.IP` for `inet` types. You probably want to use [this](https://github.com/kyleconroy/sqlc#type-overrides) and map `inet` to plain `string` and then change your parsing code accordingly. While `::1` is a valid value for `inet` that's not what is actually being sent to the database, it is the raw bytes that are being sent (try printing `fmt.Printf("%q\n", []byte(arg.Ip))` and you'll see what I mean. And btw the reason you're seeing `::1` in your prints is because `net.IP` implements ...

Comment: ... the `Stringer` interface, however that interface is not used when sending data to the db.

Comment: @mkopriva Yep, I see what you mean now. Thanks for the help, brother/sister. :)

Comment: so where is the answer to his question? was really hoping to see an accepted answer @mkopriva mind posting an answer?

Comment: @uberrebu I didn't provide an answer because I don't use `sqlc` nor `chi` and therefore I do not know what the correct solution to the problem is. However I'm familiar with Go and PostgreSQL so I thought I may at least be able to provide some suggestions, which I did, in the comments, as you can see. If you would like to know how Rario ended up solving the issue you should probably ask them to provide the answer. If you have a similar Go+PostgreSQL+IP question but unrelated to sqlc then prehaps you should open a new question, I'd definitely take a look at it and help if I can.